# The Buddha and the Jhanas

Tags: reference-request, the-buddha, pali-canon, jhana

This is a continuation of an original question I asked, linked here: [Buddhist Jhanas, how best to describe them?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/29256/buddhist-jhanas-how-best-to-describe-them)

My question is: can any of you link me directly to the instances in primary sources (likely the Pali canon) where the Buddha either enters the Jhanas, or discusses the Jhanas?

I have found the Buddha entering the Jhanas on his deathbed, but am specifically looking for the instance where he spontaneously enters the Jhanas at a ploughing festival in his youth, or where he discusses the Jhanas with his students.

Thank you!

Comment: Jhāna is an important keyword to understand tipitaka. Most short sutta, which had an enlightened one at the end, were taught for the attained jhāna practitioner, such as dhammacakkappavattanasutta. Khandha-word, aggregates, was used by the jhāna practitioner before the buddha appear to the world.

Answer (score 4):

The Buddha already attained the 1st jhana when he was a child as per [MN 36](https://suttacentral.net/mn36/en/bodhi):

> I considered: ‘I recall that when my father the Sakyan was occupied, while I was sitting in the cool shade of a rose-apple tree, quite secluded from sensual pleasures, secluded from unwholesome states, I entered upon and abided in the first jhāna, which is accompanied by applied and sustained thought, with rapture and pleasure born of seclusion."

In [MN 26](https://suttacentral.net/mn26/en/bodhi), the Buddha already mastered both Rupa and ARupa jhanas when studying under the two masters Alara Kalama and Uddaka Ramaputta. The topic of Jhana in general was discussed extensively in many suttas, here're [some examples](https://accesstoinsight.org/index-subject.html#jhana).